# Verifying a hashed salted password that uses yescrypt algorithm

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, password, cryptography

In order to verify a password hash we can use `openssl passwd` as shown below and explained [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/passwd.1ssl.html)

`openssl passwd $HASHING-ALGORITHM -salt j9T$F31F/jItUvvjOv6IBFNea/ $CLEAR-TEXT-PASSWORD`

However, this will work only for the following algorithm: md5, crypt, apr1, aixmd5, SHA-256, SHA-512

How to calculate the hashing password, from bash or python or nodeJS for a $CLEAR-TEXT-PASSWORD, with salt using yescrypt ?

Comment: Related: [The format of encrypted password in \`/etc/shadow\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/642570)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`perl`'s `crypt()` or `python3`'s `crypt.crypt()` should just be an interface to your system's `crypt()` / `crypt_r()`, so you should be able to do:

```
$ export PASS=password SALT='$y$j9T$F31F/jItUvvjOv6IBFNea/$'
$ perl -le 'print crypt($ENV{PASS}, $ENV{SALT})'
$y$j9T$F31F/jItUvvjOv6IBFNea/$pCTLzX1nL7rq52IXxWmYiJwii4RJAGDJwZl/LHgM/UD
$ python3 -c 'import crypt, os; print(crypt.crypt(os.getenv("PASS"), os.getenv("SALT")))'
$y$j9T$F31F/jItUvvjOv6IBFNea/$pCTLzX1nL7rq52IXxWmYiJwii4RJAGDJwZl/LHgM/UD
```

(provided your system's `crypt()` supports the yescript algorithm with the `$y$...` salts)

Comment: Attn Stefan Chazelas
Can you give the solution for bash, still with openssl ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dominique, those will also work with bash or your system's sh. A shell is a tool to run other tools. Here `perl` and `python3` are two examples of tools that can query your system's `crypt()` function. AFAIK, `openssl` is not such a tool.